# Is it ok to use an argument named "arguments" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, naming

I'm writing a library that exposes the following function

```
function call(instance, func, arguments) {
  return {
    call: {
      instance: instance,
      func: func,
      arguments: arguments
    }
  }
}
```

Is the name `arguments` ok to use? It's really the best name for it, but I don't want to clash with the builtin variable. It works in Node. Will this work in all browsers and JavaScript environments?

**Edit:**

Note that the above function *does work as expected* in Node. What I'm wondering is whether this will work everywhere.

I'd rather not rename it unless there's a technical reason to. I'd really like this external-facing function and the docs to reflect this parameter name, because the returned object is going to be serialized as JSON and used across languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is okay to use the name `arguments` in "sloppy mode", but not recommended.

It is forbidden in strict mode, which all new code should use if the author cares about code quality.

```
function a(arguments) {
    console.log(arguments);
}
a(1);
// Prints "1"

(function () {
    'use strict';
    function a(arguments) {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
    a(1);
}());
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
```

This is akin to naming a variable "Object". Maybe in some obscure context it makes sense to use that name, but by doing so you lose access to the global `Object` object and useful methods on it like `Object.keys`. Similarly, by making this poor naming decision, you can no longer manipulate the `arguments` object, which is varargs in JS.

In the interest of improving the maintainability of your code, it is best to avoid creating ticking time bombs like this one. There is a good reason why it is not allowed in strict mode: It is likely to cause misery for anyone who wants to use `arguments` as it is typically used.

Comment: Strict mode is important, so that makes reusing the name technically infeasible. Thanks for this example.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that is taken. `arguments` is a quick, array-like way to get all the arguments of a function. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) explaining it.

Maybe you could use `parameters` instead?

**EDIT:** To see how this variable works, I wrote this:

```js
function sayHelloTo(objectToSayHiTo){
  alert("Hello "+arguments[0]+"!");
}

sayHelloTo("world");
```

**EDIT #2:**

Apparently, it will not be affected:

```js
function sendGreetings(name, arguments){
    alert("I'm "+name+"!");
    for(var count=0;count<arguments.length;count++){
      alert("Hello "+arguments[count]+"!");
    }
}

sendGreetings("kittycat3141", ["world", "StackExchange", "Joe"]);
```

However, I haven't tried all browsers yet.

**EDIT #3**
I have tried 5 major browsers (IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera) and the code above works properly. **However**, as iCobot said in the comments, it is best not to use builtin names because it can save you confusion and frustration later, for you and anyone reading the code.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath why not?

Comment: "Will this work in all browsers and JavaScript environments?".

Comment: Yeah, that's the object I'm concerned about. What I'm wondering is whether I can still use that same name *despite* the built-in object. (In Node, you can.)

Comment: @Joe - Your best bet is not to use any word that is already built in.  Even if it would work across all environments, it's just good etiquette for other developers who may ever need to look at your code.  And even yourself down the road.  Less possible confusion.

Comment: @iCobot I generally agree. In this case, however, more eyes will be on the external-facing parts of it than inside the function. It's also a small function, so it shouldn't be confusing to those who do happen to peek inside.

Comment: @Joe - It's your code, do what you want with it.  In my view, etiquette is etiquette regardless how large or small the code is and regardless how much attention the code will actually get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @kittycat3141. I went with the other one because I was really looking for a technical reason here, not a social one. Ideally, the quirks of JavaScript wouldn't influence a cross-language API too much, but looks like there is indeed technical reason to break consistency.

Comment: @Joe - Social ones can be a part of the technical ones as well.  Coding etiquette is just as important at times as the actual technical explanations.  It keeps things consistent for all developers instead of coding with quirks.  There is more to programming then just the technical aspects and that goes for a lot of things in life.  Food for thought.

Comment: @iCobot True. I do agree with you.